# running "exec()" under "windows+apache+php5.4" slower than command line

Tags: php, apache, exec

For some reason I need to run a **C++** program in **Windows** + **PHP**. **PHP** code like:

```
$start = microtime();
exec("test.exe");
$end = microtime();
```

When I ran this php file as `php test.php` in command line, "test.exe" told its cost time is 11s. But I ran it with apache in browser like `localhost/test.php`, it finally output it costed 252s.

Is it any limit in apache when it fork a new process, or something else?

---

btw, "test.exe" is a program that I wrote to analyze data with windbg.

I use a few data to test its performance.

i. directly use "test.exe"

```
CDumpAnalyze::Analyze time cost[2.328000]
```

ii. call with php command line.

```
$start = microtime();
system("cd F:\\DumpPlatform\\bin\\server && test.exe --cfg=dump_config.ini --gameversion=10000");
//exec("dir");
$end = microtime();

echo $start."\n";
echo $end."\n";

CDumpAnalyze::Analyze time cost[2.982000]
0.09448800 1378104101
0.11078900 1378104104
```

iii. run with apache

```
CDumpAnalyze::Analyze time cost[63.158000] 
0.53862700 1378104642 
0.75394800 1378104705
```

Comment: Well, how long does `test.exe` take on its own? The PHP script will take *at least* that long, plus the time it takes for PHP to parse the script (which should be insignificant).

Comment: @josecarlos 11 seconds. It will output its running time after finished. btw, the text.exe is a program that I wrote to analyze data.

Comment: Where does the **test.exe** file stored? In the current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is no difference in time cost execution of your `test.exe`. So the difference is related to your web server and how it handles `PHP` scripts. Apache is a `Thread Safe` web server and there are many scheduling and other process tables exist in order to manage Thread safety on it. Besides, the time that your system costs for searching the path from Apache `exe` file to your `test.exe` file may play important role in exceeding the time cost in your case.

You can test your program on other web servers and post the results for exact comparison.

Comment: That sounds reasonable ! I did same test above in Linux, and they costed almost same time.

Comment: In addition, I tried to output some system info in `exec` mode by using `wmic cpu`. And I found that in window `apache+php` mode has a lower cpu clock speed than php command mode.